# Не могу понять логику задачи и по какой логике написан код у задачи

Tags: java

не могу понять как можно решить данную задачу

Владимир представляет на научной выставке свою установку, состоящую из N лампочек, со- единенных в одну цепь. Внезапно он узнает, что установки, как у него, демонстрирующиеся на выставке, должны быть красивой. Установка считается красивой, если в ней некоторое количество лампочек(возможно нулевое) подряд начиная с начала выключено, а оставшаяся часть включена.
Например: цепь 0000111 является красивой, а цепь 00010011 нет, где 0 - это выключенная лам- почка, а 1 - включенная.
Каждую лампочку на установке можно включить или выключить.
Начало выставки уже скоро, и Владимиру нужно сделать свою установку красивой за минимальное количество включений/выключений лампочек.
Ниже я предоставил код решения задачи, но я не понимаю алгоритмическую логику, почему именно так сделан код.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scanner.nextLine();

        int totalDisabled = 0;
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == '0') {
                totalDisabled++;
            }
        }

        int answer = totalDisabled;
        int disabled = 0;
        int abled = 0;
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == '1') {
                abled++;
            } else {
                disabled++;
            }
            answer = Math.min(answer,  + totalDisabled - abled);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Ниже я предоставил код решения задачи, но я не понимаю алгоритмическую логику, почему именно так сделан код._  Людвиг Аристархович интересуется, а кто это сделал?

Comment: А зачем его понимать? Он неправильно считает.

Comment: 1) Задача не совсем понятна, начиная с определения "красивости" установки.  2) Непохоже, что представленный код как-то решает поставленную задачу: первый цикл вычисляет количество выключенных ламп, второй цикл считает опять же общие количества включенных и выключенных ламп, и вычисляет значение `answer` странным образом.  Для простейшего набора данных из двух _одинаковых_ ламп ответ будет неправильный.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если имеется последовательность 0 и 1, и мы **находимся в некоторой позиции** этой последовательности (указатель `^`)

```
011100101110
     ^
000000111111
 ###   *   *
```

то нетрудно увидеть - для получения красивой последовательности, в которой нули и единицы будут разделяться **после** данного индекса, нужно:

а) обнулить все **единицы, которые встретились до этого момента** - в приведённом коде это значение `abled`,  позиции помечены `#`

б) установить все **нули, которые находятся правее** (помечены `*`) - а их количество легко найти как разность общего количества нулей `totalDisabled` и тех, что уже встретили слева `disabled`.

Таким образом, при вычислении минимума (при обходе всех возможных позиций разделения) должно использоваться выражение

```
totalDisabled - disabled + abled
```

Comment: В приведённом коде `abled` и `disabled` считают разные состояния ламп во _всей_ последовательности, а не до какого-то определенного индекса.  Если вдруг _"красивой"_ окажется последовательность с нулями слева и единицами справа, то для входного значения `011100101110` достаточно будет переключить четыре нуля кроме самого первого, чтобы получить `011111111111`

Comment: @NowhereMan Нет, не во всей, а только в той части, которую прошёл второй цикл [online](https://onlinegdb.com/k93x-baIsg)

Comment: Так второй цикл _тоже_ проходит по всей строке `for (char c : s.toCharArray())`  :) [forked online](https://onlinegdb.com/eEtsneJFQ).  И позиция заданного индекса для красивости не определена.

Comment: @NowhereMan Позиция не нужна, достаточно лучшего значения.  А цикл этот, насколько я понимаю, эквивалентен `for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {  char c = cs[i];`    (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), и обходит по порядку, а не как попало. Второй цикл проходит по всей строке, но на каждой итерации ведь обработана только начальная часть строки. Для последней строки третья позиция обработана, получили `off=2   on=1    -> answer=2` - два нуля, одна единица, ответ остался, как и на прежнем шаге.

Comment: И почему для первых трёх позиций (подстроки "001") ответом будет 2?  Эта подстрока выглядит вполне "красиво" согласно начального "определения" _некоторое количество лампочек(возможно нулевое) подряд начиная с начала выключено, а оставшаяся часть включена_.  Соответственно здесь минимум равен 0; как вариант -- достаточно было бы переключить один ноль.

Comment: Красивой должна стать вся строка, а не начальная подстрока, поэтому переключение оставшихся (ещё необработанных нулей) с этой позиции пока смотрится выгодно.

Comment: @MBo я так понял, что мы должны итироваться по каждой "лампочке" и смотреть, базируясь на наш список выключенным лампочек totalDisabled, все что левее нашей лампочки на которой мы находимся мы выключаем, что правее включаем?

Comment: @Kiawem Про `базируясь на наш список выключенным лампочек totalDisabled` мне фраза непонятна, но `все что левее нашей лампочки на которой мы находимся мы выключаем, что правее включаем` - верно. В общем - да, проверяем все варианты именно так, выбираем лучший.

Comment: @MBo я про то что мы в первом цикле пробежались по строке и собрали значения в totalDisabled, Это были все нули в нашей строке