# Не могу придумать логику для решения задачи

Tags: алгоритм

Не приходит идея для решения задачи, подскажите пожалуйста какую логику можно придумать для задачи ниже

**На вход подается строка String, строка считается красивой, если ее подстроки имеют одинаковую длину, а также одинаковый набор символов, который одинаков. Пример красивых строк:
011011011; 101101101; 1010; 1; 0000; 111
Некрасивые строки: 000101; 10101; 0001001
Цель задачи: вывести минимальное количество шагов, за которое можно исправить некрасивую строку.**

*ПРИМЕР:
000101 - 1
так как мы можем изменить 0 на второй позиции на 1 и получим 010101
0001001 - 2
мы можем заменить все единицы на нули.*

Идея считать нули и единицы, а потом из большего вычитать меньшее не подходит так как на первом примере получится что 4(нуля) вычесть 2(единицы) будет ответ 2
но как можно увидеть исправить можно за 1 шаг.
Я думал что может создать заготовки (скажем там "красивые" заготовки, например 11; 00 И так далее), но по факту можно иногда просто поменять все цифры на противоположные и получится короче. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: А вы с прошлым вопросом уже разобрались?? И формулировка этой задачи некорректная. Приводите точное условие

Comment: Непонятно. Например, 011011011 — подстроки и 0110, и 11 — с разной длиной etc. Может, состоящая из нескольких одинаковых подстрок?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу понять логику задачи и по какой логике написан код у задачи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1572967/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8)

Comment: @MBo, как видите ещё есть нюансы в определении "красивости" :)

Comment: задачи как раз разные, длина строки может быть до 10^9 степени

Comment: @Harry
вы правы состоящая из одинаковых подстрок и по длине тоже

Comment: @MBo с прошлым вопросом разобрался, спасибо большое!

Comment: @NowhereMan это не дубликат, ибо в первой задаче, у нас по условию допускается строка и считается красивой вида 011111, то есть по условию строка считается красивой если вначале стоит 0( может отсустововать), а остальные идут единицы.
Тут же условия в том, что надо смотреть на строку и делить ее на одинаковые, как по длине, так и по символам наборы подстрок

Comment: @MBo, эта задача сложнее поиска периода. Я пока придумал для всех периодов (делителей длины) отыскивать максимум общих битов, отличающиеся менять. Сложность N*sigma_0(N). В принципе сигма растёт не быстро, может прокатить.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Верно, я уже и забыл, что по условию нужно строку изменить. Но честно говоря, задача сложновата для (неолимпиадного? не знаю, как назвать) курса

Comment: @MBo суть в том, что дана строка, мы смотрим на нее и должны понять за сколько шагов можно сделать ее красивой, какой строка подается не оговаривается, то есть она сразу может быть красивой, но то что строка не нулевая это точно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть *n* - длина строки *s*. Переберём все её собственные делители *d*: *d|n, 1 ≤ d < n*.

Для каждого делителя вычислим число изменений строки чтобы сделать её красивой с периодом подстроки *d*. Для этого будем перебирать позиции в периоде *k*, *0 ≤ k < d*.

Рассмотрим символы с индексами *s<sub>k</sub>, s<sub>d+k</sub>, s<sub>2d+k</sub>, ...*. Если среди них больше нулей, то выгоднее заменять единицы нулями. Если наоборот, то заменим нули на единицы. Так или иначе мы отыскали минимальное число замен чтобы сделать разряд *k* периода *d* красивым. Чтобы сделать весь период красивым надо сложить число замен для всех разрядов.

За линейное время вычислено число замен до красивого периода *d*. Чтобы решить задачу в целом надо найти минимум числа замен по всем периодам. Сложность решения *O(nσ<sub>0</sub>(n))*, где *σ<sub>0</sub>* - [число делителей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Искать делители *n* можно линейным поиском. Это не самый эффективный способ сам по себе, но в случае этой задачи линейный поиск мажорируется рассчётом расстояния до красивого периода.

[ESkri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/529431/eskri) в комментарии предложил "разбивать строку только на простое кол-во подстрок". Рассмотрим *d<sub>1</sub>*, *d<sub>2</sub>*: *d<sub>1</sub>|d<sub>2</sub>|n*. Тогда строка красивая по периоду *d<sub>1</sub>* оказывается также красивой по периоду *d<sub>2</sub>*. То есть при поиске минимального количества замен период *d<sub>1</sub>* можно не рассматривать: минимум замен по *d<sub>1</sub>* не меньше чем минимум замен по *d<sub>2</sub>*.

Если количество периодов *m = d/n* - составное число, его можно разложить в произведение *m = m<sub>1</sub>m<sub>2</sub>*, *1 < m<sub>1</sub>, m<sub>2</sub>*. А тогда *dm<sub>1</sub>* - делитель *n* больший *d*. Следовательно рассматривать составные количества периодов не имеет смысла.

Новый алгоритм: переберём все *p* - простые делители *n*. Для каждого *p* вычислим *d = n / p*, для которого вычислим число замен. По всем *p* выберем минимум числа замен. Задача решена. Сложность *O(nω(n))*, где *ω(n)* - [число простых делителей *n*](https://oeis.org/A001221). Она растёт медленнее *σ<sub>0</sub>(n)* (и медленнее *log(n)*), что даёт заметный выигрыш по времени.

Comment: а подскажи пожалуйста как пришел к такому решению

Comment: Это просто перебор всех возможных решений. Повезло, он кажется достаточно эффективным.

Comment: да, очень, ибо я думал вообще над многими вариантами, но вот про делители вообще не пришло в голову, Спасибо за помощь!!

Comment: достаточно разбивать строку только на простое кол-во подстрок.  Получится O(n*n/log(n))

Comment: @ESkri, потерян случай для периода длиной единица. И ваша оценка стала значительно хуже, а должна быть лучше. С самой оптимизацией я согласен, она улучшает, только не понимаю как сильно.

Comment: да, оценку я написал неправильную )))

Comment: @ESkri, спасибо! По вашему комментарию дополнил ответ. Если *n <= 10^9*, то *omega(n) < 10*. Практически линейный алгоритм.

Answer (score 0):

Подскажите, пожалуйста, разве предложенное выше решение от [Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121/stanislav-volodarskiy) не разбивается о пример "111000001"?

Я так понимаю оно выдаст 3 и будет что-то типо:
"101010101".
А можно сделать и за два шага, заменив два последних 0:
"111000111"

Comment: у нас же строка считается красивой когда в ней:
a) - подстроки одинаковой длины
б) имеют одинаковые символы (последовательность)
 то есть 111 000 111 как бы соблюдены все условия, но нет ибо у нас сначала идут единицы, а потом нули

Comment: я подправил условия задачи, для более правильной формулировки условия

Comment: @Kiawem спасибо за пояснения!!!